# WARNING: Line <x> split at 64 KB in <myfile>

Tags: textpad

Using Textpad this error appears when searching files that have very long lines.  It pollutes the tool output window with these messages, hiding relevant search results.  How can I turn this off please?

Comment: "Find in Files stopped searching files with lines longer than 64 KB. Now they are split at that length." is listed under 'Issues resolved' in TextPad 8.1.0 at https://www.textpad.com/support/relnotes.html Sounds like this feature has been added as a solution, but I agree the warning messages clutter the search results!